# How to render variable in ejs from socket.io in real time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, ejs

I am using node.js, ejs and socket.io. I don't know how to pass variable to client from socket.io.

If I wouldn't use ejs and only work with HTML I would do it in this way:

Server:
`

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('message', (msg) => { // I receive message from my microcontroller
    console.log(msg);
    io.emit('temptofront', (msg));
  });
});
```

`Client:`

```
    <p id="test1">test1</p>
    <p id="test2">test2</p>

    <script>

        var socket = io();
        var test= document.getElementById("test1");
        var test2= document.getElementById("test2");
        socket.on('temptofront', (msg) => {
            console.log(msg);
            test1.innerHTML = msg[0];
            test2.innerHTML = msg[1]
        })
        </script>
```

`

I am new with ejs and I don't know how to generate variable by ejs.

Answer (score 0):

EJS runs once the server and generates (in this case) some HTML. Your server side code then sends it to the client.

The EJS program does not keep running. It can't connect to a WebSocket. It can't update itself and cause the server to send some new HTML to the client.

However, it **sends HTML to the client** which the client uses to build a standard DOM environment. The client can use client-side JavaScript to connect to the WebSocket just as it could with a static HTML document. The client doesn't know or care how the server determined what HTML to send, it only sees HTML.

Comment: Thanks you. Is it possible to put raw html in .ejs file?